# multiple nokia maps with infobubbles on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented several nokia maps on one page with several markers etc. To accomplish this I created a nokia map object containing the configs and functions needed and extended this object to have an object for each map.

Works fine, I get all the markers shown in each map. The problem is, that the infobubble component can only be attached to one map / display.

Im using nokia maps api 2.5.4 http://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.4/jsl.js

A small js snippet how I initiate those maps:

```
var map1, map2, ..,
var nokiaMap = {
  appId : ...
  authToken : ...
  infoBubbleContainer : new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles(),
  ...
  init : function(){....},
  initMap : function() {
    var me = this;
    this.map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById(this.mapContainerId), {
        zoomLevel: zoom,
        components: [
            new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
            new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar (),
            new nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector(),
            new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar(),
            me.infoBubbleContainer
        ],
        center : [this.lat, this.lon] ...
  }

//call the maps
map1 = jQuery.extend(true, {}, nokiaMap);
map2 = jQuery.extend(true, {}, nokiaMap); ...
```

The error message:

```
Uncaught Error: IllegalArgument: Error: A component can only be attached to one display!
```

Anyone got a solution for this problem or a workaround?

Comment: simple way is change `nokiaMap` into function that returns the object so a new InfoBubbles gets created each time

Comment: how do you mean that? duplicating all the code? I'm already extending the nokiaMaps object to have a map1, map2 object with the same variables and functions to use.. so shouldnt this already create a new infobubbles object?

Comment: no need to duplicated code, just `return` object from function

Comment: I already have 2 different objects? map1.infoBubbleContainer and map2.infoBubbleContainer. Can you give me an example cause right now I can't really follow you..

Comment: `var nokiaMap = function(){ return {authToken : ...
  infoBubbleContainer:...};})`  then `map1 = nokiaMap();map2 = nokiaMap();`

Comment: The approach to change the nokiaMap object into a function returning all the object stuff and calling the function with map1 = nokiaMap(); map1.init(params); works! big thx to @charlietfl